Deriving contours from .las files
I am trying to derive different contour lines from my LiDAR data. I am running in to an interesting error though (see attached picture). Any idea on how to rectify this? Smoothing?


That's typical of really dense data. The only thing you can do is decimate points.

If you didn't apply a low-pass filer Filter(...,filter_type='LOW',...), you should certainly do that.
